# How to change tag and also set id in mootols?

Tags: mootools

I have an DOM structure like below

```
<dt id="helloworld">Features</dt>
```

I want to change it like below using mootools

```
<div id="helloworld">Features</div>
```

How to do that? Basically the third tag changes from dt to div? I am new to mootols please. Can you give me an example please. There is only helloWorld in the page

I tried below

```
$$("#helloworld").each(function(el) {
     new Element("div", {
        html: el.get("html")
    }).replaces(el);
});
```

It does replace the tag. But I also lose the id :(

Comment: It was solved by giving extra arguments to the new Element. Thanks. It is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the ID also as a property of [the element constructor](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Element/Element#Element:constructor):

```
$$("#helloworld").each(function(el) {
     new Element("div", {
        html: el.get("html"),
         id: el.get('id')
    }).replaces(el);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/09tvfjdj/